# Looking for resources that help testing a Haskell implementation for standard conformance

Tags: haskell

I browsed around a while on haskell.org, haskell-prime wiki, etc. but did not find any resources like test suites, or some such, that would allow to check a Haskell implementation for standard compliance.

Does anybody know if such resources exist, and point me there?

Otherwise, I wonder what the Haskell Prime Comitee would do if someone claims that he has a Haskell-2010 compliant implementation?

Comment: I doubt anyone cares. Get users, and they'll make sure you're being compliant.

Comment: "what the Haskell Prime Committee would do if someone claims that he has a Haskell-2010 compliant implementation"? They're not the police... Hell, the most popular implementation (GHC) isn't even 2010-compliant.

Comment: Out of curiosity do you have a link to the implementation?

Comment: @DanielWagner It is *not*? I always thought it was, and the GHC extensions are built on top?

Comment: @jozefg I speak of a hypothetical case. But I have a personal interest insofar as I want to make Frege (see my profile) as indistinguishable as possible, even if it will most likely never really be Haskell.

Comment: @Ingo: There are a variety of [minor discrepancies between the Report and what GHC does](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/bugs-and-infelicities.html#vs-Haskell-defn).

Comment: If you _do_ end up creating a test suite that others could use as well (or even creating an initial fragment of one), then that would itself be a great contribution!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Aside from the written standards for [Haskell 2010](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/) and [Haskell98](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/), I don't think there is an "official test suite" for compliance. If you are developing a Haskell implementation, perhaps you can adapt the [GHC test framework](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/Building) to suit your needs.